# For encoding/json, how can I gracefully handle an API JSON call that contains apostrophes in key names?

Tags: json, go

I am writing a simple Go program to consume a simple API. 
Some values are not correctly unmarshaling into my struct, and I have traced the issue to the invalid key names in the returned JSON object.

I can reproduce the issue with this code:

```
jsonStr := `{
    "valid_json": "I'm Valid",
    "invalid'json": "I should be valid, but I'm not"
}`

type result struct {
    Valid   string `json:"valid_json"`
    Invalid string `json:"invalid'json"`
}

var res result
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &res)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Valid:   %s\n", res.Valid)
fmt.Printf("Invalid: %s\n", res.Invalid)
```

The resulting output:

```
Valid:   I'm Valid
Invalid:
```

My expected output:

```
Valid:   I'm Valid
Invalid: I should be valid, but I'm not
```

I've tried options such as escaping the `'` in the struct tag, but this either results in an error or it is just ignored.  I've also looked into alternate methods but have come back empty-handed.

How would this issue be properly handled on my end? Would it be better to strip the `'` before unmarshaling? Or is there some other way that I could accept the single quote?

Comment: It's refreshing to see a well-researched question about Go and JSON, that hasn't been asked a thousand times before! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs for [json.Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)...

> The key name will be used if it's a non-empty string consisting of only Unicode letters, digits, and ASCII punctuation except quotation marks, backslash, and comma.

The relevant code appears to be [`isValidTag`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/480373c7560cd64e4b6c624d84e9d0de6d72c076/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L838). According to the comment, "quote chars are reserved" for future use in the tag syntax.

```
func isValidTag(s string) bool {
    if s == "" {
        return false
    }
    for _, c := range s {
        switch {
        case strings.ContainsRune("!#$%&()*+-./:<=>?@[]^_{|}~ ", c):
            // Backslash and quote chars are reserved, but
            // otherwise any punctuation chars are allowed
            // in a tag name.
        case !unicode.IsLetter(c) && !unicode.IsDigit(c):
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

You can work around this by using an interface instead of a struct.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)
func main() {
    jsonStr := `{
        "valid_json": "I'm Valid",
        "invalid'json": "I should be valid, but I'm not"
    }`

    var res interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    m := res.(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range m {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case float64:
            fmt.Println(k, "is float64", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range vv {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
}
```

See "Decoding arbitrary data" in [JSON and Go](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) for more.

Comment: Good catch!  I was thinking it was an issue with the "encoding/json" library, so I didn't even think to look at the struct tag definition. The actual API nests this 3-4 levels down, so I'll need to implement this to confirm everything works, but for now, I'll be marking this answer accepted.